# Group by max Date in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a requirement, Here is my problem
I have certain postal codes along with creation dates, I want to group the postal codes based on max creation date, once a postal went into a first group its should not repeat into other groups

Please refer below image

If I select a filter creation date is **"August"**,  then
Postal code 20097, 20249, 20459 has two creation dates  Aug and Jun, based on my requirement, these postal codes should go in group 1, and the next group will form which are postal codes having next maximum creation date and not in the group 1

[image]

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

An LOD on postal code can return the max date of each.

```
{FIXED [postal code] : max([creation date])}
```

Use this field as your date (in the viz or filter shelf) and then you can count distinct postal codes.

```
COUNTD([postal code])
```

Take a look at https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod.htm for more information on LODs.